# Name 'enemy' not defined - Python

Tags: python, function

My code isn't working properly, it says that enemy is not defined when I have defined it:

```
class Gnome:
    def __init__(enemy, name):
        enemy.name = name
        enemy.health2 = 50
        enemy.health = enemy.health2
        enemy.attack = 7
        enemy.goldgain = 6
GnomeIG = Gnome("Gnome")

class Goblin:
    def __init__(enemy, name):
        enemy.name = name
        enemy.health2 = 38
        enemy.health = enemy.health2
        enemy.attack = 5
        enemy.goldgain = 3
GoblinIG = Goblin("Goblin")

class Wolf:
    def __init__(enemy, name):
        enemy.name = name
        enemy.health2 = 20
        enemy.health = enemy.health2
        enemy.attack = 3
        enemy.goldgain = 1
WolfIG = Wolf("Wolf")
```

This is the game:

```
def prefight():
    global enemy
    enemynum = random.randint(1, 3)
    if enemynum == "1":
        enemy = GnomeIG
    elif enemynum == "2":
        enemy = GoblinIG
    elif enemynum == "3":
        enemy = WolfIG
    fight()
```

All the lines with 'enemy.something' give the error that it is not defined.

```
def fight():
    print("You have encountered a %s!" % enemy.name)
    print("Player Life: %d/%d | Enemy Life: %i/%i" % (PlayerIG.health, 
           PlayerIG.health2, enemy.health, enemy.health2)) 
    print("Potions: %i\n" % PlayerIG.potions)
    print("1. Attack")
    print("2. Drink Potion")
    print("3. Run")
    option = input("> ")
    if option == "1":
        attack()
    elif option == "2":
        drinkpotion()
    elif option == "3":
        run()
    else:
        fight()
```

Error:

File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Proj/rpg.py", line 231, in

main()

File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Proj/rpg.py", line 51, in main

start()

File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Proj/rpg.py", line 65, in start

start1()

File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Proj/rpg.py", line 84, in start1

wild()

File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Proj/rpg.py", line 104, in wild

fight()

File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Proj/rpg.py", line 118, in fight

print("You have encountered a %s!" % enemy.name)

NameError: name 'enemy' is not defined

Comment: You could [define `fight` with an `enemy` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) and pass an enemy when you call it.

Comment: @wwiii How would I go about doing that? I'm new to Python and this is the majority of my knowledge, any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: Work your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) to get an overview of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problems. Unfortunately this isn't a tutoril or discusion forum.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code generates an **integer** between 1 and 3

```
enemynum = random.randint(1, 3)
```

Your conditionals, however, test against strings.

```
if enemynum == "1":
```

This means that none of your if or elif statements will ever be entered and therefore enemy will never be defined because a string will never equate to an integer.

To fix this, change your if and elif statements to check if enemynum is equal to 1, 2, or 3 as an **integer**
e.g.

```
if enemynum == 1:
    enemy = GnomeIG
```

Comment: Correct. I would consider removing the conditional completely using [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice): `enemy = random.choice([GnomeIG, GoblinIG, WolfIG])`

Comment: @YannVernier This might have helped a bit, but it still shows that it's not defined.

Answer (score 0):

> Error:
>
> File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Proj/rpg.py", line 231, in
>
> main()
>
> File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Proj/rpg.py", line 51, in main
>
> start()
>
> File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Proj/rpg.py", line 65, in start
>
> start1()
>
> File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Proj/rpg.py", line 84, in
>   start1
>
> wild()
>
> File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Proj/rpg.py", line 104, in wild
>
> fight()
>
> File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Proj/rpg.py", line 118, in
>   fight
>
> print("You have encountered a %s!" % enemy.name)

It look like you call main() -> start() -> start1() -> fight() and **never actually call prefight()**. So it never have a chance to introduce this variable named enemy.